# Likelyhood ratio for a sequence of populations

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have a sequence $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ of n=20 independent random variables that follow a normal distribution such that

$X_n \sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$)

Getting one unique sample of $X_n$ for each value of n, can I use the likelihood ratio testo to do hypothesis testing. Is there a problem if every sample belongs to a different population? As far as I understand it should be ok but books define the LR test for just one single population.

Thank you

Comment: It would be a problem. You can standardised all of the samples by minusing the mean and dividing by the standard deviation (assuming they're all normally distributed). Then you can do a likelihood of getting all $20$ data points (by calculating the likelihood of the transformed data under a $N(0,1) assumption$.

Comment: I understand your point. Transforming the data is probably the best solution, but why it would be a problem without transforming the data? You could easily construct the likelihood functions both for the restricted parameter space and the relaxed parameter space and then find the values of sigma and mu that maximize the expressions, right? Finally apply same ideas: ratio value is close to 1 then the H0 is true, value close to 0, reject H0

Comment: it probably would not be a problem, however the calcs would not simplify nearly as well haha